# Showing comments only to same custom user role

Tags: comments, comments-template

Is there a way I could show only the comments by a particular user role to his same user role?

For example: The logged in user belongs to the "Advertisers" user role, he should only see the comments made by him and all users under his role.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need this for front and back end? just front? just end?

Comment: @bynicolas By front and back end, what do you mean? Basically this will be for viewing only of the comments on posts.

Comment: I mean, does this restriction need to be applied on the front end only or does the users have access to the wp dashboard (and also access the comments by the dashboard)

Comment: @bynicolas It will be on front end only. They don't need to see the list of their comments on dashboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can,

**Frontend only**

you would need to check each post comment author for it's role. If the role of that comment author is not *adverstisers* then remove it from the array of comments attached to that post.

Then you would have to return only the comments if the current logged in user is also from the *advertisers* role.

using the [`comments_array`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/comments_array) filter we can go over each comments attached to a post. But this filter is applied in comments_template so it won't affect the access comments in backend.

Here's how you can do it

```
add_filter( 'comments_array' , 'wpse_filter_by_role_frontend' , 10, 2 );
function wpse_filter_by_role_frontend( $comments, $post_id ){

  $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); // retrieve the currently logged in user

  // go over each comments for the current post
  foreach( $comments as $key => $comment ){

    $comment_author = new WP_User( $comment->user_id ); // for each comment get the author user object

    // here we say unset the current comment if the role of the comment author is not the same as the role of the logged in user
    if( $comment_author->roles[0] != $current_user->roles[0] ){
        unset( $comments[$key] );
    }

  }

  // Return the filtered $comments array 
  return $comments;


}
```

**Frontend and backend**

```
add_action( 'pre_get_comments' , 'wpse_hide_for_backend' );
function wpse_hide_for_backend( $comments_query ){

 // Hide all for non logged in users 
 if( !is_user_logged_in() ){
    return $comments_query->query_vars['comment__in'] = array(0);
  }

  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

  // if you don't want to apply restrictions to admins
  if( $current_user->roles[0] == 'administrator' ){
    return $comments_query;
  }

  $user_ids = get_users( array( 
    'role__in' => $current_user->roles, 
    'fields' => 'ID' 
  ) );

  $comments_query->query_vars['author__in'] = $user_ids;

}
```

**EDIT**

I modified the second function.

Seeing @birgire's answer I realized there was an `author_in` query arg and using `get_users` with query arg `role__in` we can achieve the desired effect on both front and back end.

So thanks to @birgire for the inspiration :)

**EDIT**

To allow more than just the role of the current user in the fetching of comments (like adding comments made by administrators) simply append the array in `role__in` with the desired roles

so the function would become

```
add_action( 'pre_get_comments' , 'wpse_hide_for_backend' );
function wpse_hide_for_backend( $comments_query ){

 // Hide all for non logged in users 
 if( !is_user_logged_in() ){
    return $comments_query->query_vars['comment__in'] = array(0);
  }

  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

  // if you don't want to apply restrictions to admins
  if( $current_user->roles[0] == 'administrator' ){
    return $comments_query;
  }

  $user_ids = get_users( array( 
    'role__in' => array(
      'administrator',
      $current_user->roles[0],
    ), 
    'fields' => 'ID' 
  ) );

  $comments_query->query_vars['author__in'] = $user_ids;

}
```

or (for readability on this forum)

```
$permitted_roles = array(
  'administrator',
  $current_user->roles[0],
);

$user_ids = get_users( array( 
    'role__in' => $permitted_roles, 
    'fields' => 'ID' 
  ) );
```

Comment: +1 I think your approach would scale better than my untested suggestion. I guess OP also want to modify the output of `get_comments_number()`? I didn't address that

Comment: It's true that my approach doesn't affect comment count either.  It will show total amount of comments regardless of filtering applied here.  We would need to add another filter to [`wp_count_comments`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_count_comments/) to address that issue

Comment: @bynicolas How can I show all the comments made by the admins to all the users?

Comment: which code are you using, the one for front end or the other one?

Comment: @bynicolas The second one.

Comment: `role__in` takes in an array of roles, you could create your `permitted_roles` array and add to it, the current user's role plus the administrator role. I will update the answer with that specification

Comment: @bynicolas Can I ask you one more question? Is there a way I can hide the reply of the admin to the other role in the dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way (untested) to display comments from users in the same role as the current user:

```
add_filter( 'comments_template_query_args', function( array $args )
{   
    // Nothing to do for visitors
    if( ! is_user_logged_in() )
        return $args;

    // Nothing to do for threaded comments    
    if( isset( $args['hierarchical'] ) && 'threaded' === $args['hierarchical'] )
        return $args;

    // Get current user
    $u = wp_get_current_user();

    // Nothing to do for users without any roles
    if( ! isset( $u->roles ) ||empty( $u->roles ) )
        return $args;

    // Fetch user ids with the same role
    $user_ids = get_users( [ 'role__in' => (array) $u->roles, 'fields' => 'ID' ] );

    // Restrict comment authors
    if( ! empty( $user_ids ) )
        $args['author__in'] = (array) $user_ids;

    return $args;

} );
```

Here we assume the user base is not huge and we use the  `comments_template_query_args` filter to target the main comments query in the `comments_template()` part in the theme.

Comment: With this answer, you are not hiding comments for non logged in users. so everyone can see the comments if they are visitors.

Comment: yes, that's true. OP didn't clarify the case for visitors only, so I didn't handle that here, just mentioned it in the code snippet so that OP could adjust it ;-) @bynicolas

Comment: You are right, I just assumed that if OP didn't want users with different roles to see comments, he didn't want visitors either !